# ¿Cómo acumular datos en una matriz que está en otra clase?

Tags: java

Primero que todo esto es para un proyecto que tengo en la U. Es un juego de cartas, donde el usuario juega contra la maquina, y si implementan el código la finalidad del juego es completar mil millas.

Entonces lo que necesito es poder llamar desde una clase la matriz que tengo en otra clase, para que cuando corra el programa, yo pueda ingresar un dato en una posición, y luego de eso, al salir de la matriz el dato haya quedado guardado. 
En el siguiente código, al correr el programa yo voy al menú y ahí ingreso a la matriz, luego guardo un dato en una posición, pero al guardar esa posición y volver al menú, ese dato se elimina, y es como si comenzara desde 0 cada vez que ingreso a la matriz. Lo que necesito es que se vayan guardando los datos.

Este es el método de la clase donde llamo la matriz:

```
static Scanner leer2=new Scanner(System.in);
static int j,k, lectura,contador=1,total=0,total1=0;
static int autos[][]=new int[2][100];
static int usuario=0, pc;

public static void MenuJugador(){
Scanner leer1=new Scanner(System.in);
int x=0;
while(x!=3){
System.out.println("1. OBTENER BARAJA");
System.out.println("2. USAR CARTA");
x=leer1.nextInt();
switch(x){
case 1:
    Barajas();
    break;
case 2:
    Cartas.AñadirCartas(autos, total1, total, leer2);
    break;

}//switch
}//while
```

}

Esta es la otra clase donde tengo la matriz

```
 public static void AñadirCartas(int autos[][],int total1,int total,Scanner leer2){
        int lectura2;
         System.out.print("Ingresa el numero de la carta= ");
            System.out.println();
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
                    lectura2=leer2.nextInt();
                    if(lectura2==1||lectura2==2||lectura2==3){
                        autos[0][j]=-100;
                        autos[1][j]=-50;
                        System.out.println("Has usado la carta=[Accidente-100]");
                        System.out.println("Maquina ha usado carta=[Sin carburante-50]");
                        }
                    if(lectura2>3&&lectura2<7){
                        autos[0][j]=+25;
                        System.out.println("Has usado la carta=[Sin carburante-50]");
                        System.out.println("Maquina ha usado carta=[Millas+75]");

                    }
                    if(lectura2>6&&lectura2<10){
                        autos[0][j]=-25;
                        autos[1][j]=-25;
                        System.out.println("Has usado la carta=[Neumático pinchado-25]");
                        System.out.println("Maquina ha usado carta=[Sin limite de velocidad, Maquina ha ganado turno]");
                        System.out.println("Maquina ha usado la carta=[Neumático pinchado-25]");
                    }
                    if(lectura2>9&&lectura2<13){
                        autos[0][j]=+40;
                        //autos[1][j]=50;
                        System.out.println("Has usado carta=[Semáforo rojo=-10]");
                        System.out.println("Maquina ha usado carta=[Millas+50]");
                    }
                    if(lectura2>12&&lectura2<16){
                        autos[1][j]=+100;
                        autos[0][j]=+75;
                        System.out.println("Has usado la carta=[Reparaciones+100]");
                        System.out.println("Maquina ha usado carta=[Millas+75]");
                    }
                    if(lectura2>15&&lectura2<19){
                        autos[1][j]=+25;
                        System.out.println("Has usado la carta=[Gasolina+50]");
                        System.out.println("Maquina ha usado la carta=[Neumático pinchado-25]");
                    }
                    if(lectura2>18&&lectura2<22){
                        autos[1][j]=+25;
                        autos[0][j]=+100;
                        System.out.println("Has usado la carta=[Neumatico de repuesto+25]");
                        System.out.println("Maquina ha usado la carta=[Reparaciones+100]");
                    }
                    if(lectura2>21&&lectura2<25){
                        autos[1][j]=+10;
                        autos[0][j]=+50;
                        System.out.println("Has usado carta=[Semáforo verde=+10]");
                        System.out.println("Maquina ha usado la carta=[Reparaciones+50]");
                    }
                    if(lectura2>24&&lectura2<28){
                        autos[0][j]=+100;
                        System.out.println("Limite de velocidad, has perdido turno");
                        System.out.println("Maquina ha usado carta=[Millas+25]");
                    }
                    if(lectura2>27&&lectura2<31){
                        System.out.println("Sin limite de velocidad, has ganado turno");
                    }
                    if(lectura2>30&&lectura2<34){
                        System.out.println("Sin limite de velocidad, has ganado turno");
                    }
                    if(lectura2>33&&lectura2<37){
                            autos[0][j]=+7;
                            autos[1][j]=-10;
                            System.out.println("Has usado la carta=[Tanque roto=Regala 7 millas]");
                            System.out.println("Maquina ha usado carta=[Semáforo rojo=-10]");
                    }
                    if(lectura2>36&&lectura2<47){
                        autos[1][j]=+32;
                        System.out.println("Has usado carta=[Millas+25]");
                        System.out.println("Maquina ha usado la carta=[Tanque roto=Regala 7 millas]");

                    }
                    if(lectura2>46&&lectura2<57){
                        autos[1][j]=+57;
                        System.out.println("Has usado carta=[Millas+50]");
                        System.out.println("Maquina ha usado la carta=[Tanque roto=Regala 7 millas]");
                    }
                    if(lectura2>56&&lectura2<67){
                        autos[1][j]=+75;
                        autos[0][j]=+75;
                        System.out.println("Has usado carta=[Millas+75]");
                        System.out.println("Maquina ha usado carta=[Millas+75]");
                    }
                    if(lectura2>66&&lectura2<79){
                        autos[1][j]=+100;
                        autos[0][j]=+200;
                        System.out.println("Has usado carta=[Millas+100]");
                        System.out.println("Maquina ha usado carta=[Millas+200]");

                    }
                    if(lectura2>78&&lectura2<83){
                        autos[1][j]=+100;
                        System.out.println("Has usado carta=[Millas+200]");
                        System.out.println("Maquina ha usado la carta=[Accidente-100]");
                    }
                    if(lectura2>82){
                        System.out.println("El numero de cartas es 82");
                        autos[1][j]=-25;
                        System.out.println("Pierdes 25 Millas");                    
                        }
                    total1+=autos[0][j];
                    total+=autos[1][j];
                    if(total<1000){
                        System.out.println("USUARIO="+total);
                    }
                    if(total1<1000){
                        System.out.println("MAQUINA="+total1);
                    }
                    if(total>=1000){
                        System.out.println("HAS GANADO EL JUEGO");
                        System.out.println("USUARIO="+total);
                    }
                    if(total1>=1000){
                        System.out.println("MAQUINA GANO EL JUEGO");
                        System.out.println("MAQUINA="+total1);
                    }
                  Juego.MenuJugador(); //Aqui vuelvo al menú
                }

            }



}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la matriz que quieres conservar, `autos`?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear métodos set y get para poder acceder y manipular los datos desde otra clase.
Sería algo así:

```
public void setMatriz(int x, int y, int dato){
matriz[x][y]=dato;
}

public int getDatoMatriz(int x, int y){
return matriz[x][y];
}
```

Con estos métodos tienes control de los datos desde otras clases.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo que puedes hacer es, en el método AñadirCartas es devolver una matriz y en la clase que la llamas igualarla a la matriz que ya tienes, así:

```
//Declaración de la función, devolvemos la matriz
public static int[][] AnadirCartas(int autos[][],int total1,int total,Scanner leer2){
    ...
    return autos;
}

//En la clase donde llamas a este método
autos = Cartas.AnadirCartas(autos, total1, total, leer2);
```

Lo que deberías hacer si o si es quitar esa ñ del nombre de la función, puede dar problemas.

No te funciona porque al hacerlo como tú, la función trabaja sobre una copia de la matriz, por eso al volver a tu matriz original no se te han reflejado los cambios.